# Array not resetting in Game

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

Hey guys so i am developing a Game and i have an Array that keeps track of my 5 movie clips that are added to the stage by the array. I have a Player movie clip as well so the Player movie clip is Hittesting with all the 5 diamond movie clips which are added to the stage like so:

```
private var nPoints:Number = 5;..........

    public function addPointsToStage():void
    {            
         for (var i = 0; i < nPoints; i++)
         {
             trace(aPointsArray.length);
             points = new mcGainPoints();
             stage.addChild(points);
             points.x = startPoint.x + (xSpacing * i);
             points.y = startPoint.y - (ySpacing * i);
             aPointsArray.push(points);
         }

    }
```

Now when the Player comes in contact with all the 5 movie clips everything works fine and the output for the array looks like this:
0
1
2
3
4

Then it continues to the next level.

But say that my Player doesnt hit any of the 5 movie clips or only hits a couple of them, when the next level is started the output looks like this:
5
6
7
8
9

and when the next level is started weird things start happening like points start adding to the highscore by themselves.

I think the problem is that im not destroying the array holding the 5 movie clips correctly this is the code i use to start the next level and destroy the array:

```
if(player.hitTestObject(mcGoal_1))
           {

            //Remove all points from array/stage
            for (var i:int = 0; i < aPointsArray.length; i++)
            {

                if (aPointsArray[i].parent)
                {
                    parent.removeChild(aPointsArray[i]);
                }
                              startNextLevel();

            }
```

The mcGoal_1 is the object of the game so if the player hits the goal_1 then destroy all array objects on screen and start next level. This is the startnextlevel function.

```
private function startNextLevel():void
    {

        //add points to next stage
        addPointsToStage();


    }
```

So can you see why when the next level starts the array isnt reset back to 01234? I think thats why the game has that bug of randomly adding points. Please any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        //Remove all points from array/stage
        for (var i:int = 0; i < aPointsArray.length; i++)
            if (aPointsArray[i].parent)
                parent.removeChild(aPointsArray[i]);
        // just one statement, no braces
        aPointsArray.length=0; // clear the array itself, not just 
        // points from display list!
        startNextLevel(); // now start level
```

An incorrect order of correct statements leads to a disaster. Always check your code flow, what executes now and what then, and how many times.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're removing anything from the array.

You can use a combination of [`.indexOf()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#indexOf%28%29) and [`.splice()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29) to remove items from an array:

```
function removeMc(clip:MovieClip):void
{
    if(clip.parent) clip.parent.removeChild(clip);

    // Also remove from array.
    var index:int = aPointsArray.indexOf(clip);
    aPointsArray.splice(index, 1);
}
```

It might also be worth simply emptying the array when you `startNextLevel()`:

```
private function startNextLevel():void
{
    aPointsArray.length = 0;

    //add points to next stage
    addPointsToStage();
}
```

Comment: @Vesper I don't think speed is really a concern in the AS3 tag, unlike JavaScript or PHP where you get 5-10 answers in the first 2 minutes. I feel pretty comfortable reading through the question as best I can and then spending some time getting links together and reading over my answer :)

Comment: THanks alot! I appreciate everything.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign your array to null value. so that array will start from begining whenever you require. i hope the following code code would helps you.

```
  var nPoints:Number = 5;
  var points:poin;
  var aPointsArray:Array;
   var startPoint:Number = 0;
  var xSpacing:Number = 20;  
    var ySpacing:Number = 20; 

    addPointsToStage();

  function addPointsToStage():void
    {        
    aPointsArray = null;
        aPointsArray = new Array();

         for (var i:int = 0; i < 6; i++)
         {
             trace(aPointsArray.length);
             points = new poin();
             addChild(points);
              points.x = 100+ (xSpacing * i);
             points.y = 200 - (ySpacing * i);
             aPointsArray.push(points);
         }
    }
```

Comment: just comment that trace yar,   aPointsArray = null this will definately makes that array to null and reset the array.

Comment: Okay, you can't push anything into a null.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the help. Im still editing the code for all my levels and ill let you know how it goes! I appreciate it!